# Express routing methods actual implementation - trying to understand Express' inner workings

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So, as the title suggests I am digging through the Express code to understand a little bit more about it.

I have been using the framework for a couple of years now and I've got used to writing things such as `app.post(...)`, `app.get(...)`

Turns out there is no explicit declaration/definition of these methods within the Express code that is posted on Github. I guess they are implemented in an  arcane, functional, obscure-to-JS-beginners way in there somewhere.

I would very much appreciate an explanation as to how this is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see on [this](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L472) line there's iteration over `methods` from npm package with the same name. [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/methods) is the page of the package, it provides http method names handled by node http parser. Inside every `app[method]` function default router is initiated with `this.lazyrouter` (if it hasn't been already). Then a handler function is retrieved from router and called with arguments from the route.